# Installing tar.bz2 with no .configure but with Makefile in it

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make

I downloaded targui from sourceforge and it comes in a tar.bz2 archive with no .configure and no instructions regarding install. However, the archive contains a Makefile.
Looking at the Makefile (and what little documentation on sourcefourge) looks like the only dependencies are qt4, which are installed on my system at /usr/share/qt4, as the Makefile seems to require.

What am I supposed to do in order to install this package ?

Link to the sourceforge page:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/targui/

UPDATE

The Makefile has this comment:

> #
>
> Makefile for building: targui
>   Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.3.2) on: Fr Dez 28 12:32:13 2007
>   Project:  targui.pro
>   Template: app
>   Command: /usr/bin/qmake -unix -o Makefile targui.pro
>
> #

So, from within the directory containing the targui folder I tried:

> /usr/bin/qmake -unix -o Makefile targui.pro

but terminal says:

> qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory

UPDATE 2

Built according to NOorbert instructions. It segfaults

Fixed mainwindow.cpp so now it looks like:

```
void MainWindow::TabChanged(int i) {

if (newAct) newAct->setEnabled(i > 0);
if (openAct) openAct->setEnabled(i > 0);
if (saveAct) saveAct->setEnabled(i > 0);
if (saveAsAct) saveAsAct->setEnabled(i > 0);
```

}

and changed the tar references to /bin in the same file

.targui still segfaults

Comment: Yes please, maybe I got better luck...

Answer (score 2):

Build `targui` as in N0rbert's answer, then read below for getting the binary to run.

- The `targui` segfault on startup is due to `MainWindow::TabChanged` from `mainwindow.cpp` dereferencing invalid pointers, and adding checks here allows the program to start. For instance, change `newAct->setEnabled(i > 0);` to `if (newAct) newAct->setEnabled(i > 0);`, and do the same for the other three pointers.
- `mainwindow.cpp` contains hardcoded strings like `/usr/bin/tar` that might not point to extant binaries. For instance, Ubuntu's `tar` is in `/bin`, so fix them accordingly.

[image: targui screenshot]

Comment: Built targui according to NOrbert answer. It segfaults on startup.

Followed dssstorefile indications so now

>void MainWindow::TabChanged(int i) {

 >if (newAct) newAct->setEnabled(i > 0);
 >if (openAct) openAct->setEnabled(i > 0);
 >if (saveAct) saveAct->setEnabled(i > 0);
 >if (saveAsAct) saveAsAct->setEnabled(i > 0);
>}

Comment: See update 2 above for proper code

Comment: @ NOrbert, as far as what I want to do with it, i've been looking for a TAR GUI to back up to tape, which is beyond the capabilities of file roller and such, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install qmake for Qt4 and development packages for it:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev
```

then run `make`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xf targui-0.3_beta.tar.bz2
cd targui
make
```

and then run the application

```
./targui
```

but it segfaults on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then you should decide - what do you want to achieve by compiling application from 2008 year ten years after.
If you simply need graphical archival tool - you can use File Roller (on GNOME), Engrampa (on MATE) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get targui not to segfault, the changes to mainwindow.cpp according to dsstorefile1 answer must be done **BEFORE** and NOT AFTER compiling, according to NOrbert answer.